# Eclipse Dynamic WebProject Ear dependent project jar not found in WEB-INF/lib folder

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have a Three Project, **Project A (shared java project)**, **Project B and Project C are Appengine dynamic web project**. Both ProjectB and ProjectC has ProjectA as dependent project and it is also added to deployment assembly setting in eclipse.

The Problem is Project A jar is generated only for any one of the project (B or C) and not to both.i.e

**if projectA jar is generated for ProjectB , then ProjectC doesn't have ProjectA jar file in WEB-INF/lib folder.**

i have not idea why this is happening.

Any thoughts on how to make it work with multiple project ?

even org.eclipse.wst.common.component file for ProjectB and ProjectC are same, but jar is generated for both the project , instead generated for ProjectC alone.

ProjectB settings file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
<wb-module deploy-name="ProjectB">
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src"/>
    <dependent-module archiveName="Project1.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/Project1/Project1">
        <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
    </dependent-module>
    <property name="context-root" value="ProjectB"/>
    <property name="java-output-path" value="/ProjectB/build/classes"/>
</wb-module>
```

Project C settings file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
<wb-module deploy-name="ProjectC">
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src"/>
    <dependent-module archiveName="Project1.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/Project1/Project1">
        <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
    </dependent-module>
    <property name="context-root" value="ProjectC"/>
    <property name="java-output-path" value="/ProjectC/build/classes"/>
</wb-module>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are u using maven? or adding the jars directly in library

Comment: am not using maven, added directly

Comment: atleast can anyone confirm that we cannot add shared project to more than one other project ?